# Identify common rows between two datasets without leaking other rows

Tags: encryption

I have a file with encrypted rows containing data. So does my colleague.

We need to see what rows we have in common but can't see what rows we don't have in common.

Any idea of how we can encrypt our data so we know what we have in common and what we don't ? I feel like it's impossible since we both know the encryption key but I'm sure you have ideas.

Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

Hash (SHA-2) each row, and share the hashes. This will tell you if the row is the same, but won't leak any information if it isn't.

Comment: By doing this, if I get it correctly.

We must hash using same key (to have matching hash), so what if I send a row to my colleague that doesn't match with his. 

What prevents him from unhashing the row and getting the data ?

Comment: There is no key in SHA-2. Hash functions are not reversible (there is no "unhash"). They are not encryption functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I have been wronged by websites that can "unhash" SHA-2 (from their database entries).

Thank you sir and have a good day :)